# Checking value of mixin property in Ember integration test

Tags: ember.js, integration-testing

I'm writing an integration test for an Ember component that uses a mixin. Based on user interaction with the component, a property on the mixin's controller is toggled (boolean). How can I check that the value has been set? Should I inject the mixin's controller into the test? If so, what is the syntax? I can't find it googling. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making sure that the value has been set, I would validate that the resulting effect of setting that value has occurred, either by looking for a change in the component UI or by [hooking into an action](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/testing/testing-components/#toc_testing-actions) triggered by it.

If you see examples from the docs, they all validate things that can be checked on the UI,
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/testing/#toc_integration-tests

> Examples of integration tests are:
>
> - An author's full name and date are properly displayed in a blog post.
> - A user is prevented from typing more than 50 characters into post's title field.
> - Submitting a post without a title displays a red validation state on the field and gives the user text indicating that the title is required.
> - The blog post list scrolls to position a new post at the top of the viewport.